# Get current username in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, dev-c++

I am attempting to create a program that retrieves the current user's username on Windows using C++.

I tried this:

```
char *userName = getenv("LOGNAME");
stringstream ss;
string userNameString;
ss << userName;
ss >> userNameString;
cout << "Username: " << userNameString << endl;
```

Nothing is outputted except "Username:".

What is the simplest, best way to get the current username?

Comment: Also, this might help you: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/12076/

Comment: You should not use environment variables to retrieve the username. It is not guaranteed to exist. In general, outside of a BAT file you should not use environment variables.

Comment: If you must use an environment variable to retrieve the username, the correct one is `USERNAME` not `LOGNAME`. You may also want `USERDOMAIN`.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Use the Win32API [**`GetUserName`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. Example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>

char username[UNLEN+1];
DWORD username_len = UNLEN+1;
GetUserName(username, &username_len);
```

Comment: +1, you can use [GetUserNameEx if you'd like to control the format of the username](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724268(v=vs.85).aspx) instead of what was entered by the user. You should use `UNLEN+1` from `Lmcons.h`

Comment: @sixlettervariables: thanks, I edited. Do you by any chance know whether or not `<windows.h>` includes `<Lmcons.h>`?

Comment: I'm on my Mac, but if memory serves the answer is No. [LANMAN headers need to be brought in on separately, and I think this example agrees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676907%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I am trying to use this for a file path. Is there any shortcut or are functions always necessary?

Comment: @Andrew: I'm sorry, I don't see what the problem is with the code I posted. Exactly what file path are you trying to construct?

Comment: Putting the current username into a file path is almost always the wrong thing to do.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using `ifstream` and `ofstream` to copy a file. @nightcracker what is the variable `UNLEN`?

Comment: @Andrew: `UNLEN` is a macro defined by one of the standard Windows headers (specifically `<Lmcons.h>`) that gets replaced with the maximum username length. This is more accurate and portable than simply coming up with a random number.

Comment: @nightcracker, I checked my windows.h, and it doesn't include it.

Comment: Where is the file you're trying to copy?  Why do you think you need the username?

Comment: @HarryJohnston A simple file on the desktop. For the path.

Comment: The user's desktop isn't always in c:\Users\<username>\Desktop.  You should use the SHGetFolderPath or SHGetKnownFolderPath function, depending on which version(s) of Windows you're writing for.

Comment: This will not work as written. The second parameter needs to be a pointer to the size of the `username` buffer. When `GetUserName` returns the size will be replaced with the number of characters actually written into the `username` buffer.

Comment: I used this `GetUserName` function but what I get was the old username. I changed my user name (control panel -> user accounts) to a new one but the old one was retrieved instead.

Answer (score 9):

Corrected code that worked for me:

```
TCHAR username[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
GetUserName((TCHAR*)username, &size);
```

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 (on Windows 7), maybe it works the same way with Dev-Cpp

Answer (score 7):

It works:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>

int main()
{
TCHAR name [ UNLEN + 1 ];
DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;

if (GetUserName( (TCHAR*)name, &size ))
wcout << L"Hello, " << name << L"!\n";
else
cout << "Hello, unnamed person!\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

On windows use **USERNAME** enviroment variable or [GetUserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function

Answer (score 3):

In case `GetUserName(username, &username_len);` doesn't work when using a `char[]` as storage, you should know that `GetUserName` could be a macro solved to `GetUserNameW`. If u worked with Windows API probably u know the difference between `W` and `A`. Using `GetUserNameA` would solve the problem if you're using `char[]` as buf

Answer (score 1):

By using `getenv()` function:

```cpp
char * user = getenv("username");
cout << string(user) << endl;
```

If you want to convert into string then use:

```cpp
string userStr = string(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void funtions::_GetUserNameA()

char username[1024];
DWORD username_len = 1024;
GetUserNameA(username,&username_len);
std::cout <<"username:"<< username <<"\n";
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use the env variable USERNAME.

Comment: The %username% env variable is not safe. If you use that the user can open a cmd line and do
`set username=SomeOneElse
launchYourApp`

and he'll effectively be running your app as SomeOneElse. This can be a security vulnerability.