# 'GetUserNameA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int' to 'LPDWORD'

Tags: c++

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/11587467/2738536

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <Lmcons.h>

char username[UNLEN+1];
GetUserName(username, UNLEN+1);
```

But I got this error: 'GetUserNameA' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int' to 'LPDWORD'

Comment: Read the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432(v=vs.85).aspx). It's an input and output parameter.

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the length you pass in has to be a *pointer* to a double-word, because the function changes it based on what's returned.

Hence you should have something like:

```
TCHAR username[UNLEN+1];       // TCHAR to allow for MBCS and Unicode
DWORD len = UNLEN + 1;         //   if you're in to that sort of thing :-)
GetUserName(username, &len);
```

Comment: I *must* stop holding back on answers until I find the documentation link to include (and a quote from those docs). :-) It slows me down every time. I have to learn to post the answer first and *then* edit to add the links later. :-)

Comment: "the length you pass in has to be a pointer to a double-word"

Where is it stated that you should write "&len"

Comment: @user10056, it stated in the word "pointer" in my text and in the type definition `LPDWORD` (long _pointer_ to double-word) on MSDN. `&len` means the address of (pointer to) `len`.

Answer (score 0):

The type `LPDWORD` is actually a pointer.

You need to do something like the following:

```
char username[UNLEN + 1];
DWORD name_length = ULEN + 1;
GetUserName(username, &name_length);
```

[DWORD reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230318.aspx)

Comment: "The type LPDWORD is actually a pointer." Where is that stated?

Comment: `typedef unsigned long DWORD, *PDWORD, *LPDWORD;`
The * in front of `LPWORD` makes it a pointer.