# How to Replace Specific Windows Username Path with The User Running

Tags: c++

So what I want to do is make a username in a path be whatever user it is running under.

So for example, if the Windows user I was running this program under was named Bob, then I want to make the file on Bob's desktop. And not the one set to in the code.

I tried to explain it as well as possible, Thanks.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  std::ofstream fs("C:\\Users/SAMPLE_USERNAME/Desktop/omg it works.txt"); //makes the text file
  fs<<"Testing this thing!"; //writes to the text file
  fs.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I am using Code::Blocks if that helps at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current username in C++ on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587426/get-current-username-in-c-on-windows)

Comment: This can't be done portably, so you should add some other tag(s) besides `C++`. If you mean for Windows alone, check out [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188.aspx).

Comment: I have a similar comment as @dxiv but I was going to suggest using [`SHGetSpecialFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762204(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762494(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Since you've mentioned a Windows user, I am assuming that you
want a solution for Windows. Acquiring the username can be done
using Win32 function `SHGetKnownFolderPath`. However, note that
if you want your application to support Windows XP, then you will
have to use an older (deprecated) function `SHGetFolderPath`. You
can use this sample:

```
wchar_t *pszDesktopFolderPath;
if(S_OK == SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_Desktop, KF_FLAG_DEFAULT, NULL, pszDesktopFolderPath))
{
    // pszDesktopFolderPath now points to the path to desktop folder
    ...

    // After you are done with it, delete the buffer for the path like this
    CoTaskMemFree(pszDesktopFolderPath);
}
```

And here is an example using `SHGetFolderPath`:

```
LPTSTR pszDesktopFolderPath[MAX_PATH];
if(S_OK == SHGetFolderPathA(NULL, CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, NULL, SHGFP_TYPE_CURRENT, pszDesktopFolderPath))
{
    // pszDesktopFolderPath now points to the path to desktop folder, no need to manually release memory

}
```

Note that the third parameter represents a token of the user for which 
trying to acquire desktop location. In a case when you app is started by 
elevating privileges from standard user account to an administrator account,
the path returned by the functions mentioned above is the path to desktop
of the administrator user. If you want to get the path to standard user, you
will have to acquire token of that user and pass it as the third parameter.