# Do anyone know at least one C++/Windows function wouldn't work if runing under a wrong user?

Tags: c++, windows

Our software encountered a problem seems that if the user who installed the software and the user who operates it are not the same one, some functions might fail.

I'm investigating the problem,

[Get current username in C++ on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587426/get-current-username-in-c-on-windows)

Now I want to know one or two functions that would behave diferently under different user, so I can test the problem.

```
if(someFunction())
{
cout<<"That works under user:"<<GetUsername()<<endl;
}else
{
cout<<"That doesn't works under user:"<<GetUsername()<<endl;
}
```

Edit:

Our software already is set to require run as administrator,

[How to run application with Admin privileges using Manifest file in Visual Studio 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967949/how-to-run-application-with-admin-privileges-using-manifest-file-in-visual-studi)

Comment: The canonical example is `CreateFile` for a file with an NTFS ACL set.

Comment: A common problem is that installing a program actually writes a bunch of information in the use *profile* (files under `c:\User\username\Appdata`) or in the register under HKCU (still depending on username, because CU stands for Current User). If a different user tries to use the application, the program cannot find its informations and aborts..

Answer (score 0):

There are many functions that would exhibit this behavior, almost every function that operates outside the program itself (I guess). In modern windows, there are a lot of fine grained control over what a user can or cannot do - running as elevated user is actually a different concept (for example, elevation does not automaticly grant all permissions).