# My C++ application running under SYSTEM is unable to create new values or keys in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry how can I make it write these values?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, registry

My C++ application running under `SYSTEM` is unable to create new values or keys in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry the code seems to work fine when run as the current user but it doesn't work when running under SYSTEM. I'm not sure why this is happening but if I had to guess it's because it's not running as the current user. Is there any way to make it write to the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry without having the application run as the current user?

Here's the code that works when run as the current user but not as SYSTEM

```
void WriteToCurUsrReg()
{
     TCHAR ExplorePath[256], RunPath[256];
     TCHAR notepadexe[50] = {L"notepad.exe"};
     StringCchPrintf(ExplorePath, sizeof(ExplorePath), L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer");
     StringCchPrintf(RunPath, sizeof(RunPath), L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Policies\\Explorer\\Run");
     DWORD runvalue = 1;
    
     HKEY  hKey = NULL;
     LONG  lErrorCode = 0;

     lErrorCode = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, ExplorePath, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
     if (lErrorCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
     {
          RegSetValueEx(hKey,L"Run",0,REG_DWORD,(LPBYTE)&runvalue,sizeof(runvalue));
          lErrorCode = RegCloseKey(hKey);
          if (lErrorCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
          {
              printf("RegCloseKey Failed :%d %s %d",GetLastError() ,__FILE__ , __LINE__);
          }
     }


     lErrorCode = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, RunPath, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKey);
     if (lErrorCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
     {
          RegSetValueEx(hKey,L"1",0,REG_SZ,(LPBYTE)notepadexe,128);
          lErrorCode = RegCloseKey(hKey);
          if (lErrorCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
          {
              printf("RegCloseKey Failed :%d %s %d",GetLastError() ,__FILE__ , __LINE__);
          }
     }
     else
     {
         hKey = NULL;
         LONG lError = RegCreateKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, RunPath, &hKey); 
         DWORD dwLength = 0;
         if(lError == ERROR_SUCCESS)
         {                  
              RegSetValueEx(hKey,L"1", 0, REG_SZ,(LPBYTE)notepadexe, 128);
              lErrorCode = RegCloseKey(hKey);
              if (lErrorCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
              {
                  printf("RegCloseKey Failed :%d %s %d",GetLastError() ,__FILE__ , __LINE__);   
              }
         }
     }
}
```

There are no errors that occur when I run the program under SYSTEM, the program successfully runs and exits without issue but the function the program is supposed to perform is not complete ie: the program doesn't create any keys or values in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry.

Comment: What output do you get when it doesn't work? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: Which user do you want to write to? There is the `HKEY_USERS` key which contains the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` entries for all users

Comment: @Alan Birtles I want to write to whoever the current user is and not one user in specific.

Comment: @Skittari please define _"running under SYSTEM"_. How do you proceed to _"run your code under SYSTEM"_?

Comment: @Skittari: If your "current user" is `SYSTEM`, then how do you expect that to work? SYSTEM` doesn't have a hive under `HKEY_USERS` IIRC; `SYSTEM` uses HKLM. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` makes perfect sense for normal programs that are started by the logged-in user . However, see `RegOpenCurrentUser` for impersonation.

Comment: On a side note: the 2nd parameter of `StringCchPrintf()` is expressed in characters, not bytes, so using `sizeof()` is wrong when `TCHAR` maps to `WCHAR`, which can lead to buffer overflows. Use `_countof()` or equivalent instead.

Answer (score 1):

As you surmised, when running as the `SYSTEM` user, that is the user that `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` represents, not a logged in user.

You need to use `LoadUserProfile()` or `RegOpenCurrentUser()` to access the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` hive of another user.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: These are the APIs you need to use, so you likely did not use them properly.  Please edit your question to show the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are running your process as a Windows service otherwise you can run it as administrator and everything should work.

In case that your process is a windows service it's not sure that a user is logged on, maybe no user is using the computer at that time.

Anyway you can test is a user is logged on with the code you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11587426/get-current-username-in-c-on-windows).

Of course you have to run your process/service with elevated privilegies and you can do it with a manifest file with the key:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
```